# onSelectRow is not responding

Tags: c#, jqgrid

i want when i select row to show another grid with data according to the department id of the currebt row but "Onselectrow" is not responding when i select any row

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DeptInsertionMode").val(true);
        CreateDialogForm();
        $("#GridList").jqGrid({
            datatype: "json",
            url: '<%: Url.Action("GetAllDepartments", "Departments") %>',
            editurl: '',
            colNames: ['DeptId', 'Departments', '', ''],
            colModel: [{ name: 'DeptId', index: 'DeptId', align: 'center', hidden: true },
                          { name: 'DeptName', index: 'DeptName' },
                          { name: 'Editlink', index: 'Editlink', formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: {
                              baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:',
                              showAction: "UpdateDept('", addParam: "');"

                          }
                          },
                          { name: 'Deletelink', index: 'Deletelink', formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: {
                              baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:',
                              showAction: "RemoveDept('",
                              addParam: "');"

                          }
                          }],
            pager: '#paginator',
            gridview: true,
            sortname: 'DeptId',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            width: '300',
            height: '500',
            caption: "Departments List",
            viewrecords: false,
            //multiselect: true,
            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            onSelectRow: function (rowIndex) {
                var departmenId = $(this).jqGrid().getCell(rowIndex, 'DeptId');
                var url = '<%: Url.Action("GetCoursesByDept", "Departments") %>?deptId = ' + departmenId;
                $("#CoursesList").jqGrid().setGridParam({ url: url }).trigger("reloadGrid");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you put an alert and see if url and departmentid is computed correctly. Just have alert(url) before you reload grid. If you get the alert, that means reload grid is not functioning correctly. In that case, I will move the courselist jqgrid intialization code in a method and call that method inplace of reload grid.

Comment: thank you i made an alert and figured out the problem thank you @lovekumar